# Return names of users who are never associated with a value in a certain column in any row

Tags: postgresql

Suppose I want to look at only names of people who never have a row corresponding to them which contains a certain value in another column.  For example, in the following table...

```
name   | value
-------+-------
joe    | 0
joe    | 3
joe    | 2
joe    | 3
bill   | 0
bill   | 1
bill   | 2
```

... I'd like to say something like, "give me all of the users who do not ever have a value '1' in the value column."  In this case, it would return just "joe".

In the real-life example, the table is gigantic, so it wasn't time-effective to create a subquery and do a where name not in (select * from table_name where value = 1).  Is there a more efficient way to do something like this?

Comment: `select distinct name from ztable zt where not exists (select 1 from ztable nx where nx.name = zt.name and nt.value = 1);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select name
from t
group by name
having not bool_or(value = 1)
```

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html

Comment: This works perfectly, and has made a ton of my other code way better.  I never knew about bool_or!  So cool.

Answer (score 0):

Group by the `name` and take only those having zero times `value = 1`

```
select name
from your_table
group by name
having sum(case when value = 1 then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

Comment: In 9.4+ you can instead write `having count(value) filter (where value = 1)`

Comment: And in previous versions just `having count(value = 1 or null)`

Comment: And in all DB engines you can use the query above which makes it compatible und easily to maintain.

Comment: I'm not sure it is easier to mantain. I had to spend a few mind cycles to be sure it was correct, although I have been seeing that for ages. OTOH, as I'm used to the construct `bool or null` I immediately recognize its meaning. Code compatibility between DB engines, IMO, is a moot point.

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto: I you develop a product that has to run on different DBs then queries compatible to the SQL standard are very important. I had that problem in the past.

Comment: This solution felt the most "clever" to me, and from the comments I learned a few new things.  I dig the filter, but it runs pretty slowly for me for some reason (even compared to the having count(value = 1 or null).  I'll have to see why, that's kind of strange.

Answer (score 0):

Following Query retrieves user who does not ever has value 1

```
SELECT
distinct(name) from test
where name not in (select name from test where value=1)
```

Following Query retrieves all rows that do not contain value 1

```
SELECT
* from test
where name not in (select name from test where value=1)
```

Comment: This was my first attempt, but the where clause on the last line takes a significant amount of time on the table I'm actually using.  :(  This is a good answer though!

Comment: Then you can try indexing the 'value' column to perform better

Comment: I indexed, and it did perform better!  It was a little worse than the bool_or above for my data, but I can probably use this elsewhere.  Thank you!